# Join two tables and display information view page in laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

I have two tables resource_model and resimg_model with common column resid.
resource_model contains id, name,dob and phone
resimg_model contains id,resid,respic.
I am using the following way,

My controller,

```
$resource   =   DB. ::  table  ('resource_model')
->join   ('resimg_model', 'resource_model.Id' , '=', 
'resimg_model.resid')

->select ('resource_model.name', 'resource_model.dob', 
 'resource_model.phone', 'resimg_model.respic')

 ->where ('resimg_model.resid', '=', $rid)
 ->first();
  return view ('resourceview')->with('resource', $resource);
```

In view page ,
@if(! empty ($resource))

the above will display.
 In this way I am able to display all other information except resource image.
But whenever I echo the controller I got all the information.
Anyone please help me to fix this.

Comment: you want to display image from database?

Comment: Yes, now I only able to display other details except image.

Answer (score 0):

in your table only save the image name with .jpeg extension.make sure that image must be in /public/images/ directory. then set path upto image derectory in one variable and append variable with image name that you have get from your table and in view file just in img tag set that varible.

Comment: I have another issue can you help me?

Comment: display a default Image if the specified one doesn't exists in laravel

Comment: set default value in variable. when you get null value from that column then this default value or image will be display.

Comment: I already used that , I joined two tables one of the table contains image .problem is when a user who has uploaded image then that user details display perfectly with image  but a user who hasn't uploaded doesn't display nothing.if a user doest upload image then display that user details with default image this is what I want.

Comment: in your controller set a path of default image with image name. when you get details of user from table first check if you get image from table or not. if not then set image as your controller variable.